# Fubini-Study metric for an infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Hi,

Can one define a Fubini-Study metric/Kaehler metric on the projective space of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, i.e. using the formula $\partial \bar{\partial} \log |Z|^2$? 
This should be very well-known to the experts. Anyhow I don't have much experience with infinite dimension and worried that something may go wrong. I appreciate any comments or references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to see that the definition extends if you **don't** use a formula:

The unit sphere inherits a Riemannian metric from the Hilbert space in the standard manner and since it is invariant under the circular symmetry $(e^{i\theta},x) \mapsto  e^{i\theta} x$, it will
project down to a Riemannian metric on the complex projective space.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed and Alvarez, so definition works as in the finite dimensional case.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes and can be found for example in S.Kobayashi "The geometry of bounded domains" T.A.M.S 1959 (92) 267- 290

Comment: Just a small correction. I assummed taht you mean separable Hilbert space. For wild Hilbert spaces not allowing countable orthonormal basis the above answer does not apply